# Converge and sum of function series $\sum_{n\geq 0} {\frac{\cos^{n+1}{x}}{n+1}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given the following series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} {\frac{\cos^{n+1}{x}}{n+1}}
$$
it is asked to study

1. Its pointwise convergence in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$
2. Its uniform converge in the inteval $[a,\pi/2]$, with $a>0$
3. The value of the sum where it is convergent.

I'm not really sure what convergence proof method or test should I use, and I don't an intuition of what is happening with this series. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an understanding of the convergence of $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$? Your series is the same, except "$x$" is replaced with "$\cos(x)$". Any conditions on $x$ that make $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ converge could be applied to $\cos(x)$ instead.